# Transform XML using XLST whilst using an XML Catalog file

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML that I wish to transform. I am using the `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` and associated classes to perform my Transformation.

However I am coming across and issue that the URI Resolver for the TransformerFactory seems to only resolve the catalog against the XLST file, not the XML I am transformming. This is leading me to get the following error

`I/O error reported by XML parse processing null: www.apple.com`

I've done something similar with a validator before, but it seems that the Transform class isn't going to let me use the catalog for the XML file itself, only the XLST.

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Code Example

```
private Template newTemplate(ProcessContext context, String path) 
throws TransformerConfigurationException {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    CatalogManager manager = new CatalogManager();
    CatalogResolver resolver = new CatalogResolver(manager);
    factory.setURIResolver(catalogResolver);
    return factory.newTemplate(new StreamSource(path));
}
```

Comment: If the error would be in your code, showing it here might be helpful. Usage of XML catalogs like: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xcatalogs.html

Comment: So I've added a code example, but as I said, the code, from my understanding, only uses the `CatalogResolver` to deal with the XLST, not the actual XML itself. I'm just after a solution for applying the catalog to the XML itself and not the XLST